# getting images from web link and converting it into base64string in a loop

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

i need to convert the images(fetching from web service) into base64String to store them in the SQLite database.

EDIT: I use ImageOpened so that the image is loaded/downloaded before I convert them into base64String but ImageOpened doest run. How do I achieve this task ? I mean to convert array of images into base64.

this is my code:

```
public async void LoadData()
    {
       //get Json
       string str = await Helper.getJSON(); 

       //Deserialize json
       MainClass apiData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass>(str);

       //the problem loop
       for (int i = 0; i < apiData.Categories.Count;i++ ) 
       {
           //apiData.Categoriesp[i].icon_image is the url of the image
           BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(apiData.Categories[i].icon_image,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


         //it never runs
           image.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
           {
             //code for conversion of image into memory stream
               image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
               WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
               MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
               wb.SaveJpeg(ms, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
               byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();  

               string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

             //setting imageInSql property of the list (but it never runs)
               apiData.Categories[i].imageInSql = base64String;
           }; 

       } 

        //Inserting into database
        using(var db= new SQLiteConnection(App.dbPath)){
                //geting null in imageinSql property.
                db.InsertAll(apiData.Categories,typeof(Category));  
        } 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @did you tried to set the image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None.

Comment: Then you should verify the image url.

Comment: I think you are setting CreateOptions Property inside a event handler method, you should be doing this before registering a event.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like a you are setting CreateOptions property inside the event handler.

```
image.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
{
     //code for conversion of image into memory stream
     image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
```

You should do this like-

```
image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
image.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
{
```

Try below code.

```
public async void LoadData()
{
   //get Json
   string str = await Helper.getJSON(); 

   //Deserialize json
   MainClass apiData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass>(str);

   //the problem loop
   for (int i = 0; i < apiData.Categories.Count;i++ ) 
   {
       //apiData.Categoriesp[i].icon_image is the url of the image
       BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(apiData.Categories[i].icon_image,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

      image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None
     //it never runs
       image.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
       {
         //code for conversion of image into memory stream

           WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
           MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
           wb.SaveJpeg(ms, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
           byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();  

           string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

         //setting imageInSql property of the list (but it never runs)
           apiData.Categories[i].imageInSql = base64String;
       }; 

   } 

    //Inserting into database
    using(var db= new SQLiteConnection(App.dbPath)){
            //geting null in imageinSql property.
            db.InsertAll(apiData.Categories,typeof(Category));  
    } 
}
```

Comment: yes i try putting BitmapCreateOption outsite the event...didnt work